# Weird behaviour in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, launcher, brightness, preferences

Something weird has happennd to my machine since yesterday. I recall, I had not shutdown it before that and it got switched off as battery ran out.

Now, following things are occurring

- Taking long to boot
- My preferences like the size of launcher, desktop wallpaper, keyboard shortcuts (to open explorer, browser,etc) are not working i.e. nothing is happening on pressing the key combination. Actually the preferences are missing
- On opening chromium browser I get below error
  [image]
- Also the icons I am removing from the launcher like 'ubuntu software center', amazon, libre office, are resetting and appearing again each time I login back.
- Brightness, volume increase/decrease slider is not working, looks disabled, there is nothing to slide to decrease the brightness.

As a workaround I have created a temporary account and switched to all my work there, but there tons of files present in the old account and is causing a lot of inconvenience.

Have anyone come across this weird behavior? or any info on this issue? What can I do to fix these issues. I am not sure what to google for.

Basically looks like my preferences are not being saved across any thing.

FYI: Nothing installed recently, I have not updated any software since 6.

Comment: Have you tried running these apps/commands in a terminal and looking at their errors/output? These may give you some clue to what went wrong.

Comment: Sounds like something got corrupted by the abnormal shutdown.  Have you tried starting from a Live media and running `fsck`?  What file system is your `/home` on?

Comment: Do you have a separate /home partition?

Comment: check your RAM with e.g. memtest ....; so many errors are strange